# Question about linux drivers and proprietary licencing

Tags: drivers

I am thinking to implement a kind of HCI library or application for ubuntu following the close source approach. My question is:
This library will use or interact with devices detected in USB ports with "Driver=btusb" on their properties. As source code for btusb.c is GPL, can a proprietary library or application access the USB device when USB device is supported by btusb which is GPL?

Thanks a lot
Alex

Comment: Why not? I see no problems. Licences are not about what libraries can do.

Comment: The GPL license explicitly discusses this use case. Read it!

Comment: I read it already and I found "However, as a special exception, the source code distributed need not include anything that is normally distributed (in either source or binary form) with the major components (compiler, kernel, and so on) of the operating system on which the executable runs, unless that component itself accompanies the executable."    but my doubt is not if I have to provide source code of driver or not but is the GPL licence of the driver is mandatory to turn my app also GPL or not.  Please, is this case you referred on your comment?

Comment: Do you have a specific use case? You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page, as per https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: (1/2) More concretely it is this: I want to deal with Bluetooth Low Energy without using Bluez, either by relying on internal laptop BLE interface or using an external USB BLE dongle. So I decided to implement a "small" bluez like executable using an alternative C lib (musl) to be possible to static link it hence reaching Zero dependencies. When my program deals with a BLE usb dongle, the usb dongle must be detected and mapped by linux kernel before my zero dependency app comes into the scene. The mapping operation assigns the  kernel btusb.c driver to the HCI device mapped.

Comment: (2/2) So it seems that my executable will be communicating with usb dongle through btusb kernel driver. This btusb kernel driver is GPL licenced. Suppose I want to keep source code of my zero dependecy executable closed, should I license my executable as GPL (because t uses GPL btusb kernel) or can I keep it closed source?